# How to activate/deactive Spring Security via Profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have setup two Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instance on my project.

One allows anything in, the other activates UserDigest.

The config with no control

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("secoff")
public class WebSecurityConfigSecOff extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

The config with UserDigest

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("secon")
public class WebSecurityConfigSecOn extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilter(digestAuthenticationFilter())
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(digestEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/services/ESI/*").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

}
```

These two classes also require this to be defined...

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

I would have expected that I could run the system with...

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=secon
```

And the security would be enabled.

This isn't the case though, it fails to start and give the error

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
```

It also does not hit a break point either of the two 'configure(HttpSecurity http)' methods.

It appears that neither profile is triggered. 
If I remove the @profile annotation it starts fine with security on or off.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Note: JDK 1.8, Spring 4.3.7-RELEASE

Comment: can you post the full stack trace and any additional config (bean creation, etc) that might be relevant? I tried a similiar config in a test project and it's working for me as expected (using spring boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this failure was that tomcat setEnv.bat has this set...

```
spring.profiles.active=serverMode
```

This value overrides what I was setting in Intellij as a -D param. 
Hence my profile was not active.

The other way to solve this was to move from a profile to a @value annoations...

```
@Value("${securityDisabled:false}")
private boolean securityDisabled;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if (securityDisabled)
    {
        http.anonymous().and().csrf().disable();
    }else {
        http.addFilter(digestAuthenticationFilter())
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(digestEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/services/ESI/*").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```